# Undefined symbols for architecture i386 - Updated Scringo

Tags: objective-c, xcode, scringo

I know this has been asked before and I have been through the many answers but I am still unable to resolve this after hours of trying.

I updated my Scringo and Facebook SDK's and I am now facing this problem:

```
Ld /Users/Mike/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Game_Count-hekdkbexjjzgzzaikucywmaarygl/Build/Products/Game\ Count-iphonesimulator/Game\ Count.app/Game\ Count normal i386
cd "/Users/Mike/Documents/XCode Projects/Game Count"
setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 6.0
setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk -L/Users/Mike/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Game_Count-hekdkbexjjzgzzaikucywmaarygl/Build/Products/Game\ Count-iphonesimulator -L/Users/Mike/Documents/XCode\ Projects/Game\ Count/Libraries/Flurry -F/Users/Mike/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Game_Count-hekdkbexjjzgzzaikucywmaarygl/Build/Products/Game\ Count-iphonesimulator -F/Users/Mike/Documents/XCode\ Projects/Game\ Count/Libraries/RevMob -F/Users/Mike/Documents/XCode\ Projects/Game\ Count/Libraries/Scringo -F/Users/Mike/Documents/FacebookSDK -F/Users/Mike/Documents/XCode\ Projects/Game\ Count/Game\ Count -filelist /Users/Mike/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Game_Count-hekdkbexjjzgzzaikucywmaarygl/Build/Intermediates/Game\ Count.build/Game\ Count-iphonesimulator/Game\ Count.build/Objects-normal/i386/Game\ Count.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=6.0 -lsqlite3 -framework Security -framework Scringo -framework MobileCoreServices -framework AddressBook -framework CoreText -framework Twitter -framework MapKit -framework CoreLocation -lz -framework QuartzCore -framework EventKitUI -framework EventKit -framework FacebookSDK -framework CoreTelephony -framework CoreMedia -framework AVFoundation -framework CFNetwork -framework RevMobAds -framework SystemConfiguration -lFlurry_4.3.0 -framework CoreGraphics -framework StoreKit -framework Accounts -framework MediaPlayer -framework AudioToolbox -framework MessageUI -weak_framework AdSupport -framework iAd -framework Social -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/Mike/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Game_Count-hekdkbexjjzgzzaikucywmaarygl/Build/Intermediates/Game\ Count.build/Game\ Count-iphonesimulator/Game\ Count.build/Objects-normal/i386/Game\ Count_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/Mike/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Game_Count-hekdkbexjjzgzzaikucywmaarygl/Build/Products/Game\ Count-iphonesimulator/Game\ Count.app/Game\ Count

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBWebDialogs", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Scringo
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have check all my framework dependancies and they are all there. I have no idea to check which .m file is supposed to be included in the "Compile Sources" in Build Settings.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're using the latest Facebook SDK (or at least 3.5) when using the latest Scringo versions.
It is probably some mismatch in the library versions.

Comment: Indeed, that's a common mistake. Facebook changed some APIs since 3.5 and that's what's making the linkage fail.

Answer (score 0):

Select your target from `TARGETS` and go to `Build Phases` > `Compile Sources` > `Link Binary With Libraries` section. 
Check if Scringo Framework is there. If not add it.

If it is, then it looks like your updated Scringo SDK is not compiled for i386 architecture which iOS Simulator has.

Comment: Yeah Scringo is definitely there.